# Best way to create two angled divs with background images?

Tags: html, css, background-image, skew

I am trying to create a responsive header that has two adjacent background images, split diagonally.

[image]

The placement of the angle should be adjustable like so:

[image]

Most of the ways that this can be done result in the background image becoming skewed, using transparent borders that are not responsive or using clip-path, which unfortunately lacks browser support for ie.

```css
.one,
.two {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.spotlight {
  height:350px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.one, .two {
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/150);
  transform: skewX(-20deg)
}
.one {
}
.two {
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex spotlight">
  <div class="one">a</div>
  <div class="two">a</div>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VoKWxN)

Are there any other alternative ways of going about this?

Comment: Have you tried `-ms-transform:` for Internet explorer?

Answer (score 3):

```css
body {
  overflow:hidden;
}

.view {
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  -ms-transform:skew(-5deg);
  -o-transform:skew(-5deg);
  -moz-transform:skew(-5deg);
  -webkit-transform:skew(-5deg);
  transform:skew(-5deg);
}

.left,
.right {
  bottom:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}

.left { 
  left:-5%;  
  right:50%;  
}

.right {
  left:50%;
  right:-5%;
}

.img {
  bottom:-5%;
  left:-5%;
  position:absolute;
  right:-5%;
  top:-5%;
  -ms-transform:skew(5deg);
  -o-transform:skew(5deg);
  -moz-transform:skew(5deg);
  -webkit-transform:skew(5deg);
  transform:skew(5deg);
}

.left-img {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/71829/sun.jpg);
  background-position:center center;
  background-size:cover;
}

.right-img {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/71829/moon.jpg);
  background-position:center center;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="view">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="img left-img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="img right-img"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Adjust position as you want on `.right` and `.left` class

Comment: Does it work on internet explorer or other browsers?

Comment: I have checked it was working fine :)
check this screenshot https://www.screencast.com/t/3EI4qE0AHWjU

Comment: Nice this :) @nazifa-rashid

Comment: Thanks @ariferol01